# Menu tabs, Next and Back button process

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with menu tabs and every menu contains checkbox, input fields, next and back buttons and how to disable click function for the next button and other menu tabs when  current menu that contains input fields and checkbox are empty .

JAVASCRIPT : code for next and back buttons

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $tabs = $('.tabs1 li');

    $('#back').on('click', function() {
        $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    });
    $('#next').on('click', function() {
        $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    });

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d94yQ/1/)

Comment: Where in your code you're actually checking that your fields are empty? There's plenty on answers here on SO how to test for an empty field.

Comment: yes . but i want to ask how to disable next button and menu tabs when current menu tab and fields are empty like in this link https://www.ue.edu.ph/onlineadmission/main.html in (for new applicants) - > apply

Comment: get the value using jquery and check if it is empty if not then proceed further

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish your task is to use a validation plugin. Since you're using jQuery, I'd suggest using any of the numerous jQuery validation libraries out there: http://speckyboy.com/2013/10/16/form-validation-jquery-plugins-libraries/